# git merge conflict after git amend - "Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged"

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-amend

This is what happens:

1. After a recent commit to remote master, I make a small trivial change to my local repo
2. I add `git commit --amend` and leave the same commit message as HEAD
3. I try to push the repo to master with `git push`

And now I get

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commit each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I want to understand:

1. Why this exactly happens?
2. What can I do to prevent this?
3. How do I reconcile master with local after a git amend?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You changed an existing pushed commit, creating your own version (since its content has changed)

```
 --x---Y (master: that is the X amended)
    \
     --X (origin/master)
```

That is why you have 1 and 1 different commit each between master and origin/master

> What can I do to prevent this?

Don't "amend" an existing pushed commit (only local not-yet-pushed one)

> How do I reconcile master with local after a git amend?

Simply rebase on top of origin/master, then push

```
git rebase origin/master

 --x--X---Y' (master)
      |
(origin/master)

git push

 --x--X---Y' (master, origin/master)
```

However, [jwinn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/835996/jwinn) notes in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289444/git-merge-conflict-after-git-amend-your-branch-and-origin-master-have-diver/43290456#comment128616968_43290456) that it can mean your amend goes away ("`warning: skipped previously applied commit`"), and would not be the way to get your local amend (on an already pushed commit) to `origin/master`.

Comment: Important to note that answer #3 can mean that you amend goes away ("warning: skipped previously applied commit"), and would not be the way to get your local amend (on an already pushed commit) to origin/master.

Comment: @jwinn Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility

Answer (score 4):

If you are the only one working on the project after your amend you could have run

```
git push -f origin master
```

If you are not the only one working on the project be carefull of what you do because it's rewriting history.

Here is a great article about amend :
https://medium.com/@igor_marques/git-basics-adding-more-changes-to-your-last-commit-1629344cb9a8